# Create AWS Session Manager using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I just started using Terraform with AWS and now I want to create a simple Session Manager for my EC2 instance but I can't find an example to follow
(I did it using AWS console now I want to use Terraform)

Could you please help me!
thank you :)

Comment: What within the Session Manager do you want to configure?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this module from terraform registry website:
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/gazoakley/session-manager-settings/aws/1.0.1

An example of usage:

```
module "session-manager-settings" {
  source  = "gazoakley/session-manager-settings/aws"

  s3_bucket_name            = "my-session-logs-bucket"
  cloudwatch_log_group_name = "/ssm/session-logs"
}
```

Also there is some information from a github repository:
https://github.com/gazoakley/terraform-aws-session-manager-settings

Comment: This module, although clearly explained and well-written, only configures some additional settings for Session Manager and assumes Session Manager is already otherwise working.